# `AccelerationOfFreeFall` has wrong units

Tags: bugs, units, physical-constants

**Fixed in 13.0**

---

On earth, the acceleration of free fall is around $9.81\,\text{m}/\text{s}^2$. In Mathematica,

```
g = Quantity["AccelerationOfFreeFall"]
(*    1 acceleration of free fall on the surface of the earth    *)
```

Converting to SI units gives a *velocity* ($\text{m}/\text{s}$) instead of an *acceleration* ($\text{m}/\text{s}^2$):

```
UnitConvert[g]
(*    (9.764 to 9.834) m/s    *)

$Version
(*    12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)    *)
```

A bug? Version-dependent?

Comment: No problem on 12.3.1 on windows 10.  Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx02G.png) so looks like a bug that was fixed.

Comment: @Nasser you're looking at `GravityAcceleration`, which has no error bar but has the correct units. My question is about `AccelerationOfFreeFall`.

Comment: This is strange. I swear I copied what you had there. I had no idea how it changed to `GravityAcceleration`. Must be some magic happened using the mouse. Ok, will try again:   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxF4V.png)    so now it gives same as your on 12.3,1. Clearly this is a bug then.  **Oh, I remember now**, I copied it from the posted answer, not from your question. The posted answer uses `GravityAcceleration` that is why.

Comment: Unit conversion on `Quantity["AccelerationAssociatedWithCosmologicalExpansionRate"]` gives 6.6 10^-10 **m/s^2** .

Comment: This must be a mistake in their database. For example, it is also wrong in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=AccelerationOfFreeFall): for the _Basic unit dimensions_ it says $[\text{length}][\text{time}]^{-1}$.

Comment: Has this been reported?

Comment: @kcr it's [CASE:4924593].

Comment: @Roman thanks for letting me know :-)

Answer (score 2):

I get the same thing 12.0 for Windows which seems strange to me, but with

```
Quantity["GravityAcceleration"]//UnitConvert
(*  196133/20000m/(s)^2  *)

%//N
(*  9.80665m/(s)^2  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

"AccelerationOfFreeFall" does not appear to be generally compatible with [`UnitConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert.html); and when it does convert, it provides the wrong units.

```
{#, UnitConvert[Quantity["AccelerationOfFreeFall"], #]} & /@ 
  {"Conventional", "Imperial", "Metric", "SI", "SIBase"} // 
 Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

However, highlighting `"GravityAcceleration"` in Mathematica and pressing `F1` for help, provides a link to [`StandardAtmosphereData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardAtmosphereData.html). `StandardAtmosphereData` provides the correct units

```
StandardAtmosphereData[Quantity[0, "Meters"], "GravityAcceleration"]

(* Quantity[9.8066, ("Meters")/("Seconds")^2] *)
```

or with the various `Method`s

```
StandardAtmosphereData[Quantity[0, "Meters"], "GravityAcceleration", 
   Method -> #] & /@ {"Jacchia", "InternationalStandardAtmosphere", 
  "USStandardAtmosphere"}

(* {Quantity[9.8066, ("Meters")/("Seconds")^2], 
 Quantity[9.8066, ("Meters")/("Seconds")^2], 
 Quantity[9.8066, ("Meters")/("Seconds")^2]} *)
```